# How do languages make lemmata from root words?

Tags: morphology, naturalism, semantics

(Google tells me the plural of "lemma" could be "lemmas" or "lemmata", so i chose the latter. Please tell me if it's wrong.)
From reading online and offline sources, I've gathered that lemmata are mostly semantic while roots are mostly morphological. Following this, languages should have some way of taking roots and assigning lemmata to them, giving each root a meaning.
However, I can't find any consistent sources for how a language would assign meaning this way. All I can find are word lists, which would be great if I wasn't trying to design roots with lemmata attached. Is there a process for assigning meaning to roots I should follow?
Sidenote: The language I'm working on is meant to be a PIE-analogue, and I've been looking at PIE roots on Wikipedia. The lists weren't well suited to my goals but did tell me some things about how derivation affects meaning.